# How can I add a timestamp column to my SQL Server table when I create it?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to use the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [ApplicationId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    timestamp
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC)
);
```

Can someone confirm if this is the correct way. Also can or should I give that column a name of its own?

*** Note that I am using Entity Framework. So is it okay to add a column like this but to not add it to the Application object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that `timestamp` is a poor name for that datatype (it does not store time) and somewhere along the way Microsoft did too and has deprecated the use of `timestamp` since SQL Server 2008 in favor of `rowversion` introduced in SQL Server 2000.

Your code uses a behavior of `timestamp` that it gives the column a default name, `rowversion` does not do that so you have to give the column a name.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [ApplicationId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    VerCol rowversion
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC)
);
```

Ref:
[rowversion (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)
[timestamp SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

*** Note that I know nothing about using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 2):

To add the timestamp / rowversion to an **existing table** you can do this.

```
ALTER Table OrderAction ADD [RowVersion] rowversion not null
```

It will automatically assign timestamps, you don't need to anything like `UPDATE rowversion = getdate()`

Please note that if your table is large it can take a while since it needs to add a timestamp for every row. If you have a huge table and you're using a scalable database like Azure SQL you might want to increase capacity first and/or do it during off hours.

`timestamp` data type is identical to `rowversion` datatype - it's just up to you what you call the column.

It also doesn't **need** to be in your data model to be updated by an `UPDATE` or `INSERT`. However if it isn't in your data model then you won't actually benefit from the whole point of it which is to get a simplified `UPDATE` like this:

```
WHERE ([OrderId] = @p0) AND ([RowVersion] = @p1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Application] (
    [ApplicationId]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    timestamp DATETIME NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC)
);
```

Comment: What is this and what you want..?

Comment: I think that this answer is about DATETIME not about using a TIMESTAMP, this is probably misleading.